# Chrome extension: dynamically inject css without delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, google-chrome-extension

I know I can inject `css` files in the `manifest` file like this:

```
"matches": ["some url"],
"css": ["text.css"],
```

However I want to select a `css` file with JS, because I have different themes.
So for example, if the blue theme is selected, I need to load `blue.css`.

I know I can inject `css` it like that:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var path = chrome.runtime.getURL("blue.css");
        $('<link/>', {
            rel: 'stylesheet',
            type: 'text/css',
            href: path
        }).appendTo('head');

}, false);
```

However this is too slow. Before `blue.css` is loaded, the default theme is being showed for some milliseconds and this looks **ugly**. Eh.

When I only do this:

```
var path = chrome.runtime.getURL("blue.css");
        $('<link/>', {
            rel: 'stylesheet',
            type: 'text/css',
            href: path
        }).appendTo('head');
```

Then `blue.css` is not being loaded at all.

So, how can I inject `css` files with JS without this short delay, just as it is being injected from manifest?

Comment: You cannot do this without delay. It's due to the way in which the page is constructed. JS is not executed until *long* after the CSS is.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Do you know what I can do instead then?

Comment: I'm afraid not. As I mentioned, there's no workaround for the FOUC when injecting CSS via JS

Comment: The only way i found was to set the 'skin' css in the head as it would be normally but i was doing it with PHP. The other way i found, that is not faster but looks nicer is to put an 'loading' overlay until everything is loaded and make it fade away once the all JS is done. But that might not be doable depending on your applications.

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier I'm thinking about asking for the server files so that I can do it there. By the way: thank you for that 'loading overlay' idea! It does not help me with this problem, but with another one:)

Comment: This is doable via plain `style` tags. Stylish-for-Chrome has been doing it for years. See [Flickering during CSS injection in Chrome Extension](//stackoverflow.com/a/32877612) and [How to avoid a flash of misstyled content before content scripts load in a chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/a/42013659)